# How can I reset clicks made while page loading

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have window store application. I try to navigate to a page, which is loading for some time (few seconds). The page contains several big pictures therefore it's loading for some time especially at weak devices. The problem appears when I click while the page is loading - the click will be processed when page is loaded. If user click in point where will be a button when page is loaded, button will be clicked.

How can I turn this feature off? Is there any way to reset clicks while loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of resetting the clicks on page load this can be taken care of by a better design approach.

On page load, show an indeterminate progress bar and once the image load finishes hide the progress bar and show your actual screen.

Below is an example to achieve this by putting the progress bar in a PopUp control in the 
navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e) event

```
        //Progress Bar
        ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
        bar.IsIndeterminate = true;

        //Downloading Data text
        TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
        txt.Text = "Downloading data...";
        txt.FontSize = 17;
        txt.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        txt.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

        //This could take a few seconds
        TextBlock txt2 = new TextBlock();
        txt2.Text = "This could take a few seconds.";
        txt2.FontSize = 17;
        txt2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        txt2.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

        //Please do not close the application.
        TextBlock txt3 = new TextBlock();
        txt3.Text = "Please do not close the application.";
        txt3.FontSize = 17;
        txt3.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        txt3.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

        StackPanel stk = new StackPanel();
        stk.Children.Add(bar);
        stk.Children.Add(txt);
        stk.Children.Add(txt2);
        stk.Children.Add(txt3);

        stk.VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Center;
        Grid contentGrid = new Grid();
        contentGrid.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
        contentGrid.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
        // or from LayoutGrid
        //contentGrid.Height = LayoutRoot.ActualHeight;
        //contentGrid.Width = LayoutRoot.ActualWidth;
        contentGrid.Width -= 40; // it seems that ContentDialog has some defaul margin
        contentGrid.Children.Add(stk);

        Popup dlg = new Popup();
        dlg.Child = contentGrid;
        SolidColorBrush color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        color.Opacity = 0.7;
        //dlg.Background = color;
        dlg.IsOpen = true;
```

Once the images have loaded you can choose to close this PopUp